# Formatting string as email address

Tags: c#, email, razor, asp.net-webpages

This SELECT returns the email address from the project owner:

```
var selectEmailData = "SELECT User.Email FROM Projects INNER JOIN User ON Projects.ProjectOwner = User.UserId WHERE ProjectId=@0";
var dataEmail = db.Query(selectEmailData, ProjectId);

@foreach (var row in dataEmail)
{
    @row.Email
}
```

But when I tried this:

```
var mailTo = dataEmail.ToString();
```

To send an email:

```
WebMail.Send(
    to: mailTo,
    subject: "Hello there!",
    body: "Your project is ready."
);
```

I got this: **The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address.**

Whats wrong with this code?

Comment: so what IS in `mailTo`?

Comment: What's the value of `User.Email`?

Comment: `mailTo` and `User.Mail` is the mail address from: `@row.Email`

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure…

```
var dataEMail = db.Query(…) would return a collection not a string.
```

SO...

```
var mailTo = dataEmail.ToString();
```

would return something Like "System.Collections.Generic......"

I am guessing you may want something like this

```
var selectEmailData = "SELECT User.Email FROM Projects INNER JOIN User  ON Projects.ProjectOwner = User.UserId WHERE ProjectId=@0";
var allEmails = db.Query(selectEmailData, ProjectId);

@foreach (var row in allEmails)
{
  WebMail.Send(
  to: @row.Email,
  subject: "Hello there!",
  body: "Your project is ready."
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Validation?

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$"); 
Match match = regex.Match(email); 
if (match.Success)
{
//Send email
}
else
{
//Bad email
}
```

Other way:

```
try
{
MailAdress email = new MailAddress(<enter here string>);
}
catch (FormatException fe)
{
//Bad email
}
```